# How to access stuff in one function from another, called from third in c++

Tags: c++, qt, function, class

I have this code:

```
void Forms::login() {
    LoginForm *loginForm = new LoginForm;
    loginForm->show();
}

void Forms::startGame() {
    WorldForm *worldForm = new WorldForm;
    worldForm->show();
    loginForm->hide();
}
```

So, I am trying to tie all logics to one separate file, like logics.cpp. First I was using just regular functions, but I couldn't get access to loginForm from startGame (cause I cannot simply add this into .h file, this crashes all program, don't ask why - Qt stuff. These types are QWidgets). Now what I need is:

1. How to add declaration of WorldForm & LoginForm to the root of class Forms (or to the header file), I cannot do this.
2. The final goal is to call startGame() (or, in this case, Forms::startGame() as static function) from ANOTHER class in another file, and startGame() should be able to hide loginForm, as it seemed above.

I can't do it even like this:

```
void Forms::world(int a) {
    WorldForm *worldForm = new WorldForm;
    if(a==0) {
        worldForm->show();
    }else{
        worldForm->hide();
    }
}
```

Because I need `worldForm` created only once, and this will create lots of instances 1 for each call.

Here's my code: https://github.com/ewancoder/game

Comment: you could do `static WorldForm *worldForm = new WorldForm;` to only create it once, but I dont see why you cant include the definitions in  the header file (I've done it many times in Qt). Can you post the code or an example explaining why? It appears to me that you are structuring the entire program incorrectly.

Comment: It doesn't need to be static (it shouldn't be), it just needs to be a member of Forms instead of being created locally again in the method each time.

Comment: I cannot include this to header file cause LoginForm and WorldForm is QWidget object, and QT program crashing with "QApplication must be constructed before QWidget"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are member variables and the singleton pattern done in the style of `QApplication`.

What you seem to be doing is declaring global variables of a widget type:

```
// interface (.h)
extern QWidget myWidget;
// implementation (.cpp)
QWidget myWidget;
```

This will *never* work, since the construction of such an object happens **before `main()` starts!** This is the key difference you have between Delphi and C++. In Delphi, you must *call* constructors of objects yourself. In C++, it's done automatically - and for global variables, everything is constructed by the time `main()` gets to execute. You need to use pointers instead.

The `Forms` class can be declared and implemented as shown below.

The class isn't copyable since the `QScopedPointer` isn't copyable, so we should make it explicit for the human reader. There's no good reason for this class to be copyable anyway, even if, say, we used a `QSharedPointer` instead.

The `QScopedPointer` smart pointer is used so that the forms don't leak. The destructor for `QScopedPointer` automatically frees the allocated form, if any. It can be used as a bool, it's true when it is non-null.

The class enforces an invariant that there is only one instance of it. That instance should be constructed in the `main()` function, after `QApplication`. You can access this instance from anywhere by using the static `Forms::instance()` method.

For example, in `LoginForm::on_loadButton_clicked()`, you'd use

```
Forms::instance()->world();
```

```cpp
// core.h - interface

#include <QScopedPointer>

class LoginForm;
class WorldForm;
class Forms {
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Forms)
    QScopedPointer<LoginForm> m_loginForm;
    QScopedPointer<WorldForm> m_worldForm;
    static Forms * m_instance; // declaration
public:
    Forms();
    ~Forms();
    static Forms * instance();
    void login(int act = 0);
    void world();
};

// forms.cpp - implementation

#include "core.h"
#include "Forms/loginform.h"
#include "Forms/worldform.h"

Forms * Forms::m_instance = 0; // definition
// The runtime default-constructs static class members, so technically
// the explicit initialization to a null pointer is not necessary.

void Forms::login(int act) {
    if (!m_loginForm) m_loginForm.reset(new LoginForm);
    switch(act) {
    case 1:
        m_loginForm->hide();
        break;
    default:
        m_loginForm->show();
    }
}

void Forms::world() {
    if (!m_worldForm) m_worldForm.reset(new WorldForm);
    m_worldForm->show();
}

Forms::Forms() {
    Q_ASSERT(! m_instance);
    m_instance = this;
}

Forms::~Forms() {
    m_instance = 0;
}

Forms * Forms::instance() {
    return m_instance;
}

// main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include "Classes/core.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication game(argc, argv);
    Forms forms;
    forms.login();
    return game.exec();
    // The local object instances are destructed in C++-generated-code.
    // The order of destruction is opposite to the order of definition.
    // The compiler puts the following code "here":
    // forms.~Forms();
    // game.~QApplication();
}
```

So, one might ask, why just not make everything in the `Forms` class static and be done with it? It's not really possible due to the *lifetime* of static class member variables. Such members are constructed **before** `main()` starts, and destructed **after** `main()` ends. That's a big problem, since:

1. You can't leverage smart pointers to widgets, since they will be deleted when `QApplication` isn't there anymore, and that's not allowed. You can `reset()` those pointers manually, but that really defeats the purpose of smart pointers. Smart pointers are there so that you don't have to manage memory manually.
2. Since there's no instance of the `Forms` class - it's just a wrapper for static members - the destructor won't ever get invoked, and you can't leverage C++ to clean up the members automatically.

The most you can do is make all of the *methods* static, but not the *member variables*. So, this would still be OK, but makes the method implementations cumbersome:

```
class Forms {
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Forms)
    QScopedPointer<LoginForm> m_loginForm;
    QScopedPointer<WorldForm> m_worldForm;
    static Forms * m_instance;
public:
    Forms();
    ~Forms();
    static Forms * instance();
    static void login(int act = 0);
    static void world();
};

void Forms::login(int act) {
    Forms * inst = instance();
    if (!inst->m_loginForm) inst->m_loginForm.reset(new LoginForm);
    ...
}
```

But this certainly is wrong:

```
// WRONG
class Forms {
    static QScopedPointer<LoginForm> m_loginForm;
    static QScopedPointer<WorldForm> m_worldForm;
public:
    static void login(int act = 0);
    static void world();
};
```

It's wrong since the scoped pointers get destructed, and thus the forms are deleted, after `main()` ends. You're not allowed to do anything with widgets - not even destruct them - with no `QApplication` around.

To work around that, you'd need to explicitly free the form instances in  a static destructor-like method, that you must manually call to delete the forms. Your main would then become Delphi written in C++ syntax. You have a strong bias towards Delphi idioms. Those idioms don't belong in C++ -- you must unlearn them. C++ compilers do a whole lot of code generation that required manual labor in Delphi. You are expected to leverage that.

```
// AWKWARD: Delphi code in C++ syntax
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication game(argc, argv);
    Forms::login();
    int rc = game.exec();
    Forms::destroy();
    return rc;
}

// BRAINDEAD: Delphi code in C++ syntax
class Forms {
    static QScopedPointer<LoginForm> m_loginForm;
    static QScopedPointer<WorldForm> m_worldForm;
public:
    static void login(int act = 0);
    static void world();
    static void destroy();
};
```

This hopefully explains why C++ is a much more powerful language than Delphi. In Delphi, you have to worry about a lot of things that the C++ compiler takes care of, preventing you from forgetting about something important like freeing memory or releasing other resources.

Comment: @EwanCoder You set m_instance to zero when destructing so that if you have a bug in your program and you somehow use the static method(s) after the singular instance is gone, it will be caught and cause a segfault. Otherwise you may run into trouble.

Comment: @EwanCoder The `static` keyword means that it's a class member, not an instance member. It's really a keyword that has way too many completely unrelated uses. All you need to know is that members can be class members or instance members, and here we needed a class member, since it must exist even when you don't have an instance (from static methods!).

Comment: @EwanCoder "If I create non-static internal pointer, I cannot return it within Forms::instance()" Sure you cannot, because it's a class method, not an instance method. Class methods have no access to any instances, you can only access class members from those methods. There is your answer.

Comment: @EwanCoder there's no such thing as "regular" members. All members of a class are *either* class members or instance members. The static keyword makes a member a class member (one per class's type). The lack of the keyword makes a member an instance member (one per class's instance).

Comment: And I have one more question: I have some data that I need to store like player.level and etc. I'll write proper XML parser to save and load data from xml. Is it good to store all the data within Data class and create it just like Forms class? (by QPointer) Or is it good just to store data in regular variables (like struct)?

Comment: @EwanCoder "I thought that your class LoginForm; class WorldForm; lines in header file are just hypothetical" Ewan, stop it. Just stop. What I posted is the exact, compileable code. Nothing hypothetical, except for the "..." line. Those "hypothetical" lines are so called forward declarations. You really, really need to get yourself a C++ book. Strostrup's "The C++ Programming Language", **fourth** edition (seriously, it matters that it's fourth), then first 12 chapters or so.

Comment: @EwanCoder Every one and their grandma thinks that they can write an XML parser. Have you actually read the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)? All those homegrown XML parsers are broken in subtle ways, because writing a conforming XML parser is hard, and people are deluded that it's not. Qt comes with two XML parsers: a stream one, and a DOM. Just use that and don't waste time reinventing a broken wheel.

Comment: @EwanCoder Java-style setters/getters and C++ style setters/getters are very different. In C++, you don't need a separate setter/getter, because you've got references that neither Java nor Delphi has. A "getter" that returns a non-const reference is also a setter, since what it returns is an [lvalue](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/).

Comment: @EwanCoder Using `std::string` in Qt-based code is pointless. You'll be constantly converting back-and-forth between it and QString, since all Qt methods take QString, not std::string. Is `QString` better? Just compare [`QString` api](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html) to [`std::string` one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) :)

Comment: @EwanCoder You might also look into using oxygen for documenting your code.

Comment: thx for all, I know nothing about oxygen, google says it's just xml editor; about books - from my experience the best way to learn any language is practice, so I've started this thing :) and yep, I'm using DOM, I just said it wrong.
UPD: already found some articles about storing documentation in XML. btw, I've started documenting in .txt files inspired by linux kernel documentation :)